# Angularjs how to return promise result from service to controller

Tags: angularjs, promise

`itemsService` contain `additem` function which check if promise success it adds item to the items array and pass it to the `shoppinglist` controller
thats fine
now i want also to store the promise result and pass it to the controller in `list.status`
ill use this property in the dom with `ng-if` to show error when the promise result is rejection

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('shopping', [])
    .controller('shoppinglist', shoppinglist)
    .service('itemsService', itemsService)
    .service('weightControllerService', weightControllerService);
```

### controller

```
  shoppinglist.$inject = ['itemsService'];
  function shoppinglist(itemsService) {
    let list = this;
    list.Quantity = '';
    list.Name = '';
    list.additem = () => {
      itemsService.additem(list.Quantity, list.Name);
      // 
      list.status = itemsService.status;
    };
    list.removeitem = $index => {
      itemsService.removeitem($index);
    };
    list.items = itemsService.getitems();
  }
```

### service

```
  itemsService.$inject=['weightControllerService']
  function itemsService(weightControllerService) {
    let service = this;
    let items = [];
    service.additem = (N, Q) => {
      let namePromise = weightControllerService.nameCheck(N);
      namePromise
        .then(resolve => {
          let item = { Name: N, Quantity: Q };
          items.push(item);
          // how can i return the resolve to show or hide error at dom
          service.status = resolve;
        })
        .catch(reject => {
          // how can i return the resolve to show or hide error at dom
          service.status = reject;
        });
    };
    service.removeitem = $index => {
      items.splice($index, 1);
    };
    service.getitems = () => {
      return items;
    };
  }
```

### service

```
  weightControllerService.$inject = ['$timeout', '$q'];
  function weightControllerService($timeout, $q) {
    let service = this;
    service.nameCheck = Name => {
      let deferred = $q.defer();
      let result = {
        error: false,
        message: ''
      };
      $timeout(() => {
        if (Name.toLowerCase().indexOf('cookie') === -1) {
          deferred.resolve(result);
        } else {
          result.message = 'dont buy cookies';
          result.error = true;
          deferred.reject(result);
        }
      }, 2000);
      return deferred.promise;
    };
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With promises one uses the `return` statement for resolved promises and the `throw` statements for rejected promises:

```
itemsService.additem = (N, Q) => {
  let namePromise = weightControllerService.nameCheck(N);
  var newPromise = namePromise
    .then(resolve => {
      let item = { Name: N, Quantity: Q };
      items.push(item);
      // how can i return the resolve to show or hide error at dom
      service.status = resolve;
      //RETURN value
      return items;
  })
    .catch(reject => {
      // how can i return the resolve to show or hide error at dom
      service.status = reject;
      //THROW reason
      throw reject;
  });
  //RETURN new promise
  return newPromise;
};
```

Then use the returned promise in the controller:

```
list.additem = () => {
  let promise = itemsService.additem(list.Quantity, list.Name);
  promise.then(items => {
      console.log(items);
  })
   .catch(reject => {
      console.log("additem failed");
      console.log(reject);
  });

  // 
  //list.status = itemsService.status;
};
```

This `.then` and `.catch` methods return a new promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value (or throw) of the `successCallback`, `errorCallback` (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using [promise chaining](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promises-queues).

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - The Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api)